# Finding Optimized solution for a finite set problem

Tags: python

Suppose we have a problem where we need

6 pieces of 61 cm of pipe to be cut

5 pieces of 27 cm of pipe to be cut

4 pieces of 67.97 cm of pipe to be cut
(fake data)

The manufacturer makes the pipes in

12 cm

24 cm

36 cm

48 cm

60 cm

72 cm

84 cm

96 cm

120 cm lengths
(actual what I need)

Each piece of pipe we cut must be shorter than or equal to the length of the piece we cut from
leftover pieces from cut pipes can NOT be combined

Example: We cut 61 cm from a 96 cm pipe. We have 35 cm left. We can use this 35 cm piece and cut a 24 cm piece from it. We have 11 cm left. We Cannot however combine 11 cm pieces together to create a longer piece. 11 cm is considered waste.

I want a python code to return waste and a list of the number of each manufacturer’s length.
Apparently, google says I can use "dynamic programming” to solve this problem, but idk how to implement it.

I tried using ChatGPT for some basic help with it, and I still got stuck.

```
def min_waste(pieces, lengths):
  # create a 3D table to store the results of subproblems
  dp = [[[0 for _ in range(len(lengths)+1)] for _ in range(len(lengths)+1)] for _ in range(len(pieces)+1)]

  # initialize the table with maximum possible value
  for i in range(len(pieces)+1):
    for j in range(len(lengths)+1):
      for k in range(len(lengths)+1):
        dp[i][j][k] = float('inf')

  # base case: if we need 0 pieces of a given length, the waste is 0
  for j in range(len(lengths)+1):
    for k in range(len(lengths)+1):
      dp[0][j][k] = 0

  # solve the subproblems
  for i in range(1, len(pieces)+1):
    for j in range(1,len(lengths)+1):
      for k in range(len(lengths)+1):
        if pieces[i-1] <= lengths[j-1]:
          # if we can fit the current piece in the current length, try to fit it
          # and see if it leads to less waste than the previous solution
          dp[i][j][k] = min(dp[i][j][k], dp[i-1][j][k] + lengths[j-1] - pieces[i-1])

        if k > 0:
          # if we can't fit the current piece in the current length, try to fit it
          # in a longer length and see if it leads to less waste
          dp[i][j][k] = min(dp[i][j][k], dp[i-1][j][k-1])

  # the minimum waste is the value in the bottom right corner of the table
  return dp[-1][-1][-1]

# test the function
pieces = [61, 27, 67.93]
lengths = [12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96, 120]
print(min_waste(pieces, lengths))
```

Comment: I completely forgot to mention that we are trying to reduce the amount of total waste.
I have developed a slightly working version, but it can only divide the manufacturers lengths into 2 pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found a brute-force method which solves it assuming each piece purchased can be cut into 3 smaller pieces.
`

```
def min_waste(pieces_to_cut, pieces_sold):
  
    # create a 2D table to store the difference between each element in list a and list b (aka reference table or R-Table)
    reference_Table=[[0 for _ in range(len(pieces_to_cut))] for _ in range(len(pieces_sold))]
    # create a 3D table to store the results of subproblems
    threedp = [[[0 for _ in range(len(pieces_to_cut))] for _ in range(len(pieces_sold))] for _ in range(len(pieces_to_cut))]
    # create a 4D table to store the results of subproblems
    dp = [[[[0 for _ in range(len(pieces_to_cut))] for _ in range(len(pieces_to_cut))] for _ in range(len(pieces_sold))] for _ in range(len(pieces_to_cut))]

    #fill in the reference table
    for i in range(len(pieces_sold)):
        for j in range(len(pieces_to_cut)):
            if(pieces_to_cut[j]<pieces_sold[i]):
                reference_Table[i][j] = pieces_sold[i]-pieces_to_cut[j]
            else:
                reference_Table[i][j] = -float('inf')

    #fill in the 3D table with the difference between each element in the reference table and list a
    for i in range(len(pieces_to_cut)):
        for j in range(len(pieces_sold)):
            for k in range(len(pieces_to_cut)):
                if(reference_Table[j][i]>pieces_to_cut[k]):
                    threedp[i][j][k] = reference_Table[j][i]-pieces_to_cut[k]
                else:
                    threedp[i][j][k] = -float('inf')

    #fill in the 4D table with the difference between each element in the 3D table and list a
    for i in range(len(pieces_to_cut)):
        for j in range(len(pieces_sold)):
            for k in range(len(pieces_to_cut)):
                for l in range(len(pieces_to_cut)):
                    if(threedp[i][j][k]>pieces_to_cut[l]):
                        dp[i][j][k][l] = threedp[i][j][k]-pieces_to_cut[l]
                    else:
                        dp[i][j][k][l] = -float('inf')
    
        #define a helper function to find the minimum value and its index in the reference table for a given column
    def searchmin2DTable(itemNumber):
            minimum = float('inf')
            minloc=float('inf')
            for j in range(len(pieces_sold)):
                if(reference_Table[j][itemNumber]<minimum and reference_Table[j][itemNumber]>=0):
                    minimum = min(minimum, reference_Table[j][itemNumber])
                    minloc=j
            return minimum, minloc
        #define a helper function to find the minimum value and its index in the 3D table for a given item index
    
    def searchmin3DTable(itemNumber, skipList):
            minimum = float('inf')
            minloc=float('inf')
            for j in range(len(pieces_sold)):
                for k in range(len(pieces_to_cut)):
                    if(k in skipList or k == itemNumber):# skip the element if it has already been processed or is same element as current element
                            continue
                    if(threedp[itemNumber][j][k]<minimum and threedp[itemNumber][j][k]>=0):
                        minimum = min(minimum, threedp[itemNumber][j][k])
                        minloc=[j,k] 
            return minimum, minloc
        
    def searchmin4DTable(itemNumber, skipList):
            minimum = float('inf')
            minloc=float('inf')
            for j in range(len(pieces_sold)):
                for k in range(len(pieces_to_cut)):
                    if(k in skipList or k == itemNumber):# skip the element if it has already been processed or is same element as current element
                            continue
                    for l in range(len(pieces_to_cut)):
                        if(l in skipList or l == itemNumber or l==k):# skip the element if it has already been processed or is same element as current element
                            continue
                        if(dp[itemNumber][j][k][l]<minimum and dp[itemNumber][j][k][l]>=0):
                            minimum = min(minimum, dp[itemNumber][j][k][l])
                            minloc=[j,k,l] 
            return minimum, minloc
    
  # initialize empty lists to store the results
    returnList = []
    WasteList = []
    skipList = []
    combinationList = []
    
    for itemNumber in range(len(pieces_to_cut)):
        if(itemNumber in skipList):# skip the element if it has already been processed
            continue
        if(len(pieces_to_cut)-len(skipList)==2):# if the length of list a is odd and is undivideable by 3, ...
                                        # ... set first element min to minimum using manufacturer smallest piece that will fit(2d Table)
            min2d=searchmin2DTable(itemNumber)
            min3d=searchmin3DTable(itemNumber, skipList)
            if(min2d[0]<=min3d[0]):
                returnList.append(min2d[1])
                WasteList.append(min2d[0])
                skipList.append(itemNumber)
                combinationList.append(1)
            else:
                returnList.append(min3d[1][0])
                WasteList.append(min3d[0])
                skipList.append(itemNumber)
                skipList.append(min3d[1][1])
                combinationList.append(2)
            continue
        elif(len(pieces_to_cut)-len(skipList)==1):# if available parts is equal to 1, set the element min to minimum using manufacturer smallest piece that will fit(2d Table)
            tempminimum,loca=searchmin2DTable(itemNumber)
            returnList.append(loca)
            WasteList.append(tempminimum)
            skipList.append(itemNumber)
            combinationList.append(1)
            continue

        min2d=searchmin2DTable(itemNumber)
        min3d=searchmin3DTable(itemNumber, skipList)
        min4d=searchmin4DTable(itemNumber, skipList)
        if(min2d[0]<=min3d[0] and min2d[0]<=min4d[0]):
            returnList.append(min2d[1])
            WasteList.append(min2d[0])
            skipList.append(itemNumber)
            combinationList.append(1)
        elif(min3d[0]<min2d[0] and min3d[0]<=min4d[0]):
            returnList.append(min3d[1][0])
            WasteList.append(min3d[0])
            skipList.append(itemNumber)
            skipList.append(min3d[1][1])
            combinationList.append(2)
        else:
            returnList.append(min4d[1][0])
            WasteList.append(min4d[0])
            skipList.append(itemNumber)
            skipList.append(min4d[1][1])
            skipList.append(min4d[1][2])
            combinationList.append(3)
    
    return returnList, WasteList, skipList, combinationList

# test the function
#####################################################################
#####################################################################
#6*61, 6*27, 6*17.88, 6*7.63, 2*62.95, 1*67.33
pieces = [61,61,61,61,61,61, 27,27,27,27,27,27, 17.88,17.88,17.88,17.88,17.88,17.88, 7.63,7.63,7.63,7.63,7.63,7.63, 62.95,62.95, 67.33]
lengths = [12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, 96, 120]
ManufacturerPipeList, wasteList, pipes, pipeOrder = min_waste(pieces, lengths)

def count_like_numbers(lst):
  # create a dictionary to store the counts of the numbers in the first column
  counts = {}
  # iterate through the list and count the occurrences of each number
  for row in lst:
    if row in counts:
      counts[row] += 1
    else:
      counts[row] = 1
  return counts

# print the results
print("_______________________________________________________")
print("Pipe Input: ")
for number in range(len(pieces)):
    print("Pipe # "+str(number)+": " + str(pieces[number])+" in. ")
print("_______________________________________________________")
print("Order of Pipes: ")
for number in range(len(pipeOrder)):
  print(str(lengths[ManufacturerPipeList[number]])+" in. piece with pipes "+str(pipes[:pipeOrder[number]]))
  pipes=pipes[pipeOrder[number]:]

print("_______________________________________________________")
sumPipe=0
print("Pieces to Purchase: ")
for key, value in count_like_numbers(ManufacturerPipeList).items():
    sumPipe+=lengths[key]*value
    print(f'{lengths[key]} in: {value}')
print("_______________________________________________________")
print("Waste: "+str(sum(wasteList))+" in of pipe")
print("_______________________________________________________")
print("Total Pieces of Pipe: "+str(sum(count_like_numbers(ManufacturerPipeList).values()))+" pieces")
print("_______________________________________________________")
print("Total Pipe Length Calculated(including Waste): "+str(sumPipe)+" in")
print("_______________________________________________________")
print("Total Pipe Length Needed: "+str(sum(pieces))+" in")
print("_______________________________________________________")`
```

Comment: Obviously there will never be a global optimized solution without a lot of calculations.
So this is just a local optimization.